# Select all checkboxes in a table whose rows have style display tag

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, html-table, display

I have a table with some rows having a style display tag `style="display: none;"`. I also have a a "toggle-all" checkbox. I'm trying to make my "select all" script only check the checkboxes that are visible in rows with tag `style="display: table-row;"`.

This is the script i have so far, but it checks everything, regardless of visibility. How can i check/uncheck only those that are visible?

**Script**

```
$('#select-all').click(function (event) {
   if (this.checked) {
      $(':checkbox').each(function () {
          this.checked = true;
      });
   }
   if (!this.checked) {
      $(':checkbox').each(function () {
          this.checked = false;    
       });
   }
});
```

**Toggle all checkbox**

```
<input name="select-all" id="select-all" type="checkbox" value="checked" aria-label="..." style="cursor:pointer">
```

**Table**

```
<table>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>Checkbox</td>
      <td>#</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Title</td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="display: table-row;">
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="f1" value="1"></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Number1</td>
      <td>Title1</td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="display: none;">
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="f2" value="1"></td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Number2</td>
      <td>Title2</td>
    </tr>

    ...

    <tr style="display: table-row;">
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="f3" value="1"></td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Number3</td>
      <td>Title3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>    
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`:visible` selector](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) and `.prop()` can be used to manipulate properties

```js
$('#select-all').click(function(event) {
  $('table tr:visible :checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="select-all" id="select-all" type="checkbox" value="checked" aria-label="..." style="cursor:pointer"> select-all
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Checkbox</td>
      <td>#</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Title</td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="display: table-row;">
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="f1" value="1"></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Number1</td>
      <td>Title1</td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="display: none;">
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="f2" value="1"></td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Number2</td>
      <td>Title2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="display: table-row;">
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="f3" value="1"></td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Number3</td>
      <td>Title3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can select by attribute like:

```
$(':checkbox[style="display: none;"]').each(function () {
      this.checked = false;
});
```

Comment: it is not the check box that has the style display tag, but the row in which it is contained

Comment: oops my bad sorry